# How to match columns from different dataframes in R

Tags: r

I'm sorry if I'm not phrasing this correctly and it doesn't make much sense, I'm new to this. So I have these two dataframes:

Data frame 1:

[image: df1]

Data frame 2:

[image: df2]

The first contains the latitude coordinate of every enumeration area (ea) in the dataset. The second has the answers to seven survey questions conducted in every ea. My goal is to add a column in the second dataframe (the one with the questions) that has the coordinates of every ea just like in the first dataframe.

I don't know how to match the coordinates based on the first dataframe, especially because in the second each ea is repeated several times.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Regarding your question, see `?merge` or `?dplyr::left_join`